# Not getting any response from the hyperterminal

Tags: gsm, samsung-mobile, at-command

I installed Hyperterminal and I used my samsung galaxy s3 and connected it with my laptop with usb cable.  I installed the drivers and connected to s3 as modem. It shows connected in Hyperterminal. But whenever I send any command for example,

```
AT
```

and press enter, I don't get any response.  I've tried configuring the connection according to the modem configurations and when I go to

Control Panel > Phone and Modems > Query

then I get success answer for all the commands.

Why aren't I getting any response in Hyperterminal?
I checked the user guide of the Samsung s3 and it supports AT commands. And it has a GSM Modem as well.

Comment: Hi, are you completely sure that you're connecting to the modem port?  You can see the modem port by going to Windows Device Manager, and "Modems", then right click on the S4 entry and choose "Properties".  The device probably exposes other COM ports apart from the modem one.

Comment: Yes it does. It shows COM3 and I am using the same. and sorry I did a mistake it is samsung galaxy s3.

Comment: Is this a problem only on your PC? Have you tested on other machines?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the baud rate,
by default it's 9600,
give it a try at 115200 (it work for me and saved my day)